# Is it possible to disable drag and drop for Material-Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

Everything in Material-Table is working good, but I cant find the props / option to disable Drag and Drop for columns headings. I just need it to stay the same as it is provided in code

This is how my columns and options props look like :

```
columns={[
  {title: 'Name', field: 'name', defaultSort: 'asc'},
  {title: 'Code', field: 'code'},
  {title: 'Type', field: 'type.value'},
  {title: 'Regions', field: 'regions', sorting: false},
  {title: 'Currency', field: 'currencyCode'},
]},
options={{
  showTitle: false,
  actionsColumnIndex: -1
}}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

As written in the docs, you can add grouping false in the options object.

Comment: Domino, grouping is not the case here. Setting this props to false is still allowing to use Drag and Drop and change order of columns

Comment: I am sorry I misread, That is not yet implemented but about to be [merged](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/pull/779) with the option: draggable.

Answer (score 8):

You should set `draggable` option to false

```
options={{
  draggable: false,
}}
```

As a result you wont also be able to use grouping option anymore

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, but setting `grouping: false` didn't solve my problem.

Instead I set `pointerEvents: "none"` in the `headerStyle` for each column. That way the headers won't be interactable/ draggable. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for reply Fred! Anyway there was sorting option which would be blocked by pointerEvents: "none"